# Are Application Settings reliable?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, application-settings

I'm wondering if Application Settings are reliable for storing values?

I was thinking of storing my application's XML file path in there so when I run the program, it knows where the XML file is located even if the path was changed during last runtime.

1. Is there a chance that Application Settings could forget/dispose the file path value? Or maybe anything else related to that?
2. Are there better ways to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Yes, they are reliable. 1. no 2. not without reinventing the wheel

Comment: It is a handy way to store some settings. But of course you could consider storing them in a separate config file or consider a database if you want users/administrators to be able to change specific settings.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms or Web Application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are reliable. And they will do it very well because they will take under consideration OS-specific conventions and OS user profiles. So, I'd say it's a recommended practice.

There is a small catch: A later version of your application may look for settings for its own version, even if settings for an older version exist. In that case, you'll have to make sure that your app migrates the old settings and converts them to its own, instead of ignoring them. It's quite easy.

There is a bigger catch: Moving the app to another place in the disk will cause it to consider itself a new instance and make its own settings. If you want to avoid this behavior, you'll have to consider making a strongly named assembly (which I find inconvenient, to say the least).

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, yes Application Settings is reliable and well explained by Chatzigiannak. However, I want to share with you some considerations regarding to app settings that happened here.

We are currently using an external file and we load it in the web.config. Pretty simple:

```
<appSettings file="DIR\Configuration\AppSettings.config"></appSettings>
```

This code is spread out in our 15 web sites. The file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <appSettings>
      <add key="CacheEnabled" value="0"/>
      ...
   </appSettings>
```

Then we realized that this file was growing and now it has 600 keys, cool isn't it? But this is not the worst part, each server has to have it's own configuration, so we spread this file through 7 servers... And some of them have different keys... Imagine that you have to change the path of one specific key, in all servers... We created a monster =)

Doing a code review we decided to store it in the database. A simple table with the machine IP as key and a key value JSON as the document. Not 600 columns of course.

When I told to my team I was doing that, one guy said: "Are you crazy? You will have to change 1k of this code":

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEYNAME"];
```

Indeed yes I had to change it, but I thought in a simple way, creating my own ConfigurationManager that has a NameValueCollection AppSettings inside:

```
public static class ScopeManager
{
    private static NameValueCollection _appSettings;

    public static NameValueCollection AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appSettings.IsNull())
            {
                //GET FROM DATABASE, CACHE OR SOMEWHERE ELSE
            }

            return _appSettings;
        }
    }
}
```

And the changes became:

```
ScopeManager.AppSettings["KEYNAME"];
```

I don't think we had reinvented the wheel. But we've done a way much better to deal with lots of keys/websites/servers... Seems more real world.